# NoSuchMethodError in MapsInitializer.initialize() after upgrading to Google Play Services v4.2

Tags: android, google-play-services

Today I learned the hard way that you shouldn't use "+" for the version number in your Gradle build file for dependencies.

I am using a third party SDK with a MapView that calls MapsInitializer.initialize().  It works correctly with all previous versions of Google Play Services but causes the app to crash using Google Play Services 4.2.

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapsInitializer.html) does not indicate that the method is deprecated.

Interestingly, I can't even put the code in a try/catch block - it crashes my app regardless.

For now, we've reverted to Google Play Services v4.1.32, but I'm curious if there was a breaking change.

Has anyone else had this issue?  Is there a workaround or explanation?